# Web Push Notification FCM on Mobile

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notification to users in my Web App but it is not working on mobile.

I'm using VueJs + Firebase, I use a Cloud Function to send the notification and in the service worker, I receive and handle for show to the user.

It works in the Browser on PC, but don't work in mobile 'Android', here are some code:

Cloud Function:

```
 }).then(function (aTokens) {
        const payload = {
            data: {
                title: 'Test-Title',
                body: 'Test-Body'
              }
        }

        // Send notifications to all tokens.
       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(aTokens, payload).then(res => {

           res.results.forEach((result, index) => {
             const error = result.error
               if (error) {
     console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error)            
               }
           })
     response.send('OK')
     })
    })
```

Service-Worker Function:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-   messaging.js');

var config = {
messagingSenderId: "123456789"
}
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
var title = payload.data.title;
var options = {
    body: payload.data.body
};
return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});
```

[In Browser the Notification work See The Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwHdD.png)

But in Android it doesn't work, I have the last version or chrome and firefox and I tested in both, I also put the Web app in the home screen and allowed to send notification too. But the notifications never show there.

What I need to include for I see push notifications on mobile too?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this please?